# Changing all pixels not a certain color

Tags: php, image, syntax, gd, rgb

Just for the sake of my question, lets say this function:

```
int imagecolorexact ( resource $image , int $red , int $green , int $blue )
```

We can call it up pretty easy like this:

```
$index = imagecolorexact($image, 0, 0, 0);
```

Obviously because we are talking the example in hand is about RGB colors, therefore the $red, $green and $blue values are between 0 and 255. This function returns an index of the pixel with that rgb compound.

What I need is to get the index of all pixels that their compound is **NOT** (0, 0, 0), so I'd thought to do it like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 255; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $i <= 255; $i++) {
        for($k = 0; $i <= 255; $i++) {
            $index[] = imagecolorexact($image, $i, $j, $k);
        }
    }
}
```

But this will run 255*255*255 times which is alot I quess.

**My question is:
Is there any way to simplify this?**

**Why am I asking this?**
I am trying to change all the black pixels from an image to yellow, thus that would be:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("./test.png");
imagecolorset($image, imagecolorexact($image, 0, 0, 0), 255, 255, 0);
```

And I need to change all the NON black pixels from the same image into black, thus that will be (I quess?):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 255; $i++) {
    for($j = 1; $i <= 255; $i++) {
        for($k = 1; $i <= 255; $i++) {
            $index = imagecolorexact($image, $i, $j, $k);
            imagecolorset($new, $value, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Thus I am asking if there is a better, optimized way?**

Comment: If you first change all black pixels to yellow, then all non-black pixels to black, you'll end up with a completely black image. I'm not too familiar with what methods gd offers here, but it would probably be a lot easier to inspect all pixels, save the x,y coordinates of all black pixels into an array, make a new black image and paint yellow pixels into the saved locations.

Comment: Well, yes, it's correct running the image pixel by pixel (x,y). 

Thus I am running the image as an 3D matrix, image height lines, image width columns and the triplet (r,g,b) on each position.

Comment: I agree with @deceze who give an example like `$x = $y; $y = $x;` : you can solve this problem by using an alternative and unused color in your image. Set all black pixels to an unused color (if those are pictures, use a flasy color such as extreme pink 0xFF00FF), then turn yellow pixels to black and finally, pink pixels to yellow (`$swap = $x; $x = $y; $y = $swap;`). And, don't iterate the 16k colors of the palette: iterate throught your image (`$sx = imagesx($image); for ($x = 0; ($x < $sx); $x++) ...`).